# DRCSim + Precise + Hydro + roslaunch

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have Gazebo 3.0, gazebo_ros_pkgs-current, and the default branch of drcsim all compiling from source successfully with ROS Hydro and Ubuntu Precise. Now when I run

> roslaunch drcsim_gazebo atlas.launch

I get a lot of errors in the terminal:

> [atlas_robot_state_publisher-3] process has died [pid 3701, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher joint_states:=/atlas/joint_states __name:=atlas_robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/atlas_robot_state_publisher-3.log].
> log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/atlas_robot_state_publisher-3*.log

> [multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-4] process has died [pid 3714, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher joint_states:=/multisense_sl/joint_states __name:=multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-4.log].
> log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-4*.log

> [tf2_buffer_server-5] process has died [pid 3730, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/tf2_ros/buffer_server __name:=tf2_buffer_server __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/tf2_buffer_server-5.log].
> log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/tf2_buffer_server-5*.log

> [multisense_sl/stereo_proc-6] process has died [pid 3747, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl-stereo_proc-6.log].
> log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl-stereo_proc-6*.log

> [multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc_simulation_relay-13] process has died [pid 4155, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc __name:=stereo_proc_simulation_relay __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc_simulation_relay-13.log].
> log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/40b7e942-82ec-11e3-904a-d43d7e05aeaf/multisense_sl-camera-stereo_proc_simulation_relay-13*.log

Has DRCSim been tested with Hydro yet? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5277/drcsim-+-precise-+-hydro-+-roslaunch/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2014-01-21**:
looks like a bunch of ros nodes are not coming up properly. Did you source ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/drcsim/setup.sh before roslaunch?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-01-21**:
Indeed, if you are using a catkin workspace, you should source install/setup.bash and install/share/drcsim/setup.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This was due to an unrelated ROS core bug: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/342#issuecomment-33271508

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0